# ActionView::Template::Error: wrong number of arguments (Simple Form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, actionview

I have a Rails 4 app that always worked, but now a page with a simple_form_for is generating an error. I dropped all the code, leaving just the simple_form_for and still yet I'm getting error.

The page with errors (_form.html.erb):

```
<%= simple_form_for @anuncio do |f| %>
<%= f.input :titulo %>
<% end %>
```

When I execute this page, I get this error:

```
F, [2015-01-08T16:16:21.920151 #19971] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)):
    1: <%= simple_form_for @anuncio do |f| %>
    2: <%= f.input :titulo %>
    3: <% end %>
  config/initializers/simple_form.rb:100:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  app/views/anuncios/_form.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_anuncios__form_html_erb___4151327912554241759_53270140'
  app/views/anuncios/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_anuncios__form_html_erb___4151327912554241759_53270140'
  app/views/anuncios/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_anuncios_new_html_erb___954346116733613916_53199500'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the error. I have a custom def to render my label in my simple_form.rb (config/initializers/simple_form.rb). After a "bundle update", my simple_form gem was updated (to the 3.1.0 version, and also my actionview was update to the 4.2.0) and they change the arguments passed to my custom def, broken the app.

**Before (config/initializers/simple_form.rb):**

```
config.label_text = lambda { |label, required| "#{label}" }
```

**Corrected:**

```
config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{label}" }
```