# wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) error with forms

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, simple-form, ransack

I have upgraded my ruby version to ruby 2.6.6p146 and rails version to 4.2.8.
After updating the devise version is 4.6.0 and ransack version is 1.8.10.
Now on run time when I am trying to load my form for user login and it is using devise it is providing me this runtime error

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)):

I am not getting why it is happening and checked my syntax also, here is my form code

---

```
    <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %> 
       <h3 class="form-title form-title-first"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Event Admin Account Login</h3>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username or Email</label>
        <%= f.text_field :login, :placeholder => "Username or Email", :class => "form-control" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password", :class => "form-control" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
          <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> Remember me
          <% end %>  
         </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Sign in", :class=> "btn orange btn-lg" %>
    <% end %>
```

---

I have tried every version of devise and after that I am at the current version, also tried to degrade ransack version, but it didn't help

Here is the stack trace

```
Started GET "/auction_admin/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-05-02 10:55:11 +0530  

Processing by AuctionAdmin::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered auction_admin/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/home (1088.8ms)  

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1207ms (ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)): 
11:       <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>  
 app/views/auction_admin/sessions/new.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_auction_admin_sessions_new_html_erb___4037676396427670794_37299260'  
app/controllers/auction_admin/sessions_controller.rb:14:in `new' 
config/initializers/assets_silencer.rb:7:in `call_with_quiet_assets' 
Rendered /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@24f-new-ruby-2.6.6/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (17.4ms)  
Rendered /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@24f-new-ruby-2.6.6/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.4ms)  
Rendered /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@24f-new-ruby-2.6.6/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.9ms)  
Rendered /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@24f-new-ruby-2.6.6/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (39.8ms)
```

Comment: Please  share the full error message including the stack trace.

Comment: Hi, I have added the full stacktrace from my console

Comment: Do you have custom config for simple_form?
It could be something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846952/actionviewtemplateerror-wrong-number-of-arguments-simple-form

Comment: yeah, I have initializer simple_form.rb and tried the change as suggested in the link you provided, but unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: My current simple_form gem version is 4.0.0 and I have tried 3.5.0 also but still no luck

Comment: also tried form_for and nested form, they are also throwing the same error

Comment: _I have upgraded my ruby version to ruby 2.6.6p146 and rails version to 4.2.8._ From what versions? Did you do this first, then test and everything worked okay? Or did you upgrade these and then upgrade devise and THEN test? Clearly stating the order of operations and the state at each step is vital to understanding the issue.

Comment: initially my ruby version was 2.0.0 and rails version was 3.2.22.5, I have upgraded everything while upgrading steps and after that tried to run console and then fixed all the errors coming at that time. This error which I am getting now is some runtime error.Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Did you upgrade everything and only THEN test it? Or did you upgrade in small steps, testing it at each step along the way?

Comment: yeah, I upgraded everything and then tested it on locals, because of the server won't run until we fix all the issues on console.